# How to change the border of this chat box to make it look something like the one in the attached image

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, border

I would like to change the border of the message displayed in chat box , it should like the one in image , please suggest how to implement itas i have no idea how to do it .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    
body{margin-top:20px;}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
body
{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.chat_box .chat_message_wrapper ul.chat_message > li + li {
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.chat_box_wrapper.chat_box_small.chat_box_active {
    background:#e1e3e5;
    height: 600px;
    overflow-y: auto; 
    width: 450px;
}

.chat_box {
    padding: 16px;
}
.chat_box .chat_message_wrapper::after {
    clear: both;
}
.chat_box .chat_message_wrapper::after, .chat_box .chat_message_wrapper::before {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.chat_box .chat_message_wrapper .chat_user_avatar {
    float: left;
}
.chat_box .chat_message_wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.md-user-image {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 48px;
 height:48px;
}
img {
    border: 0 none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.chat_box .chat_message_wrapper ul.chat_message, .chat_box .chat_message_wrapper ul.chat_message > li {
    list-style: outside none none;
    padding: 0;
}
.chat_box .chat_message_wrapper ul.chat_message {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    max-width: 67%;
}
.chat_box.chat_box_colors_a .chat_message_wrapper ul.chat_message > li:first-child::before {
    border-right-color: #616161;
}
.chat_box .chat_message_wrapper ul.chat_message > li:first-child::before {
    border-color: transparent #ededed transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    left: -14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
}
.chat_box.chat_box_colors_a .chat_message_wrapper ul.chat_message > li {
    background: #FCFBF6 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #000000;
}

.chat_box .chat_message_wrapper ul.chat_message > li {
    background: #ededed none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    clear: both;
    color: #212121;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    position: relative;
    word-break: break-all;
}
.chat_box .chat_message_wrapper ul.chat_message, .chat_box .chat_message_wrapper ul.chat_message > li {
    list-style: outside none none;
    padding: 0;
}
.chat_box .chat_message_wrapper ul.chat_message > li {
    margin: 0;
}
.chat_box .chat_message_wrapper ul.chat_message > li p {
    margin: 0;
}
.chat_box.chat_box_colors_a .chat_message_wrapper .chat_message_time {
    color: rgba(185, 186, 180, 0.9);
}
.chat_box .chat_message_wrapper .chat_message_time {
    color: #e1e3e5;
 text-align:center;
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding-top: 2px;
 font-size:14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.chat_box .chat_message_wrapper.chat_message_right .chat_user_avatar {
    float: right;
}
.chat_box .chat_message_wrapper.chat_message_right ul.chat_message {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 24px !important;
}
.chat_box.chat_box_colors_a .chat_message_wrapper.chat_message_right ul.chat_message > li:first-child::before {
    border-left-color: #83acc5;
}
.chat_box.chat_box_colors_a .chat_message_wrapper ul.chat_message > li:first-child::before {
    border-right-color: #FCFBF6;
}
.chat_box .chat_message_wrapper.chat_message_right ul.chat_message > li:first-child::before {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ededed;
    border-width: 0 0 29px 29px;
    left: auto;
    right: -14px;
}
.chat_box .chat_message_wrapper ul.chat_message > li:first-child::before {
    border-color: transparent #ededed transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 29px 29px 0;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    left: -14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
}
.chat_box.chat_box_colors_a .chat_message_wrapper.chat_message_right ul.chat_message > li {
    background: #83acc5 none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
.chat_box .chat_message_wrapper ul.chat_message > li {
    background: #ededed none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 12px;
    clear: both;
    color: #212121;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    position: relative;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="chat" class="chat_box_wrapper chat_box_small chat_box_active" style="opacity: 1; display: block; transform: translateX(0px);">
                        <div class="chat_box touchscroll chat_box_colors_a">
                            <div class="chat_message_wrapper">
                                <div class="chat_user_avatar">
                                    <a href="https://web.facebook.com/iamgurdeeposahan" target="_blank" >
                                    <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" class="md-user-image">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
        <span class="chat_message_time">13:38</span>
                                <ul class="chat_message">
                                    <li>
                                        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio, eum? </p>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="chat_message_wrapper chat_message_right">
                                <div class="chat_user_avatar">
                                <a href="https://web.facebook.com/iamgurdeeposahan" target="_blank" >
                                    <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" class="md-user-image">
                                </a>
                                </div>
        <span class="chat_message_time">13:34</span>
                                <ul class="chat_message">
                                    <li>
                                        <p>
                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.  natus nulla perspiciatis quae quasi, quis recusandae, saepe, sunt totam.
                                            
                                        </p>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
      <div class="chat_message_wrapper chat_message_right">
                                <div class="chat_user_avatar">
                                <a href="https://web.facebook.com/iamgurdeeposahan" target="_blank" >
                                    <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" class="md-user-image">
                                </a>
                                </div>
        <span class="chat_message_time">13:34</span>
                                <ul class="chat_message">
                                    <li>
                                        <p>
                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.atus nulla perspiciatis quae quasi, quis recusandae, saepe, sunt totam.
                                            
                                        </p>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
      
      <div class="chat_message_wrapper">
                                <div class="chat_user_avatar">
                                    <a href="https://web.facebook.com/iamgurdeeposahan" target="_blank" >
                                    <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" class="md-user-image">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
        <span class="chat_message_time">13:34</span>
                                <ul class="chat_message">
                                    <li>
                                        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio, eum? </p>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My image:

[image: my image]

Comment: You should cut down all that code. We only need an example of one box that you currently have, and the example of what you are trying to make it look like

Answer (score 2):

How about a positioned pseudo-element with a radial gradient background?

This should get you close.

```css
.chat {
  width: 50%;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background: darkseagreen;
  position: relative;
}
.left {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.right {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.chat::after {
  content: '';
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.left::after {
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, transparent, transparent 72%, darkseagreen 72%);
}
.right::after {
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0, transparent, transparent 72%, darkseagreen 72%);
}
```

```html
<div class="chat left"></div>
<div class="chat right"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Paulie , This will help me a lot , I will include this code and check now.